# Can a core wallet coinbase-transaction (generation transaction) be moved intact to a net new core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, bitcoin-cash, coinbase-transaction

Can a core wallet coinbase-transaction (generation transaction) be moved intact to a net new core wallet?

Wanting to go through cautious steps to claim BCH but, I hear a BTC coinbase-transaction when still 'whole' can be worth more when sold 'whole' than the sum of the BTC in said coinbase-transaction if divided up.

In v0.14.2 bitcoin core wallet, is there a way to move a coinbase-transaction intact/whole to a net new core wallet (so it remains worth more as noted above)? Source wallet does also contain some fractional BTC that can be used for fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Any transaction that you make will make it "not whole". i.e. the "coins" move to a different output. You cannot move any coins without making a transaction.

Comment: Thank you for the quick, clear answer.  A follow up...Just looking at the current price, would it be your guess that claiming/extracting out the BCH and therefore making the coinbase-transaction 'not whole' is currently worth more than the possible additional surcharge from selling a 'whole' coinbase-transaction?

Comment: I don't think that "whole" coinbase outputs really have that much more value than "non-whole" ones. It would also be more difficult to sell one as you can't do so on an exchange. Lastly, I don't think you should try to sell it "whole" out of principle; it makes Bitcoin not fungible.